# Second Method to Find the Volume of a Slice of a Cone

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

[image]

I was looking to formulate a general solution for a vertical slice of a cone. After failing to do this by integrating for the area of an ever shrinking chord segment, I eventually came up with a more geometric solution by subtracting the triangular part from the area of a sector which was easier to integrate to get the volume and appears to work fine. See my solution sketch. However, I would still like to formulate the integration area method of the chord segment.

From the information in the sketch, integrating along a $y$ axis, the area of the segment would be:

$$A_c = 2\int_0^{\sqrt(R^2-a^2)} \sqrt(R^2 - y^2) - a \ dy$$

How do I accomplish a second integration along a vertical $x$ axis to integrate these areas into a volume with $R$ decreasing in accordance with $$r = (R - Rx/h)\text{ from } 0 \text{ to } (h - ah/R)$$

I've tried a number of ways but now I'm going cross-eyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cone of radius $R$ and height $H$

would be:
$z = H - \frac {H}{R} \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$

And we are going to slice it at some line $y = a$

$v = \int_a^R\int_{-\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}}^{\sqrt {R^2- x^2}} (H - \frac {H}{R} \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}) \ dx \ dy$

Convert to polar:

$x = r\cos \theta\\
y = r\sin \theta\\
z = z\\
dy\ dx = r \ dr\ d\theta$

$2\int_{\arcsin\frac {a}{R}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\int_{a\csc \theta}^{R}  Hr -\frac{H}{R} r^2 \ dr d\theta\\
2\int_{\arcsin\frac {a}{R}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} (\frac 16 HR^2 - \frac 12 Ha^2\csc^2\theta  + \frac 13 \frac {H}{R}a^3\csc^3\theta \ d\theta\\ 
2(\frac 16 HR^2 \theta + \frac 12 Ha^2\cot\theta - \frac 16 \frac {H}{R}a^3\csc\theta\cot\theta + \frac 16\frac {H}{R}a^3(\ln|\csc\theta + \cot\theta|)|_{\arcsin\frac {a}{R}}^{\frac \pi 2}\\
2(\frac 16 HR^2 \arccos \frac {a}{R} - \frac 13 Ha \sqrt {R^2-a^2}+ \frac 16\frac {H}{R}a^3(\ln|\frac {R}{a} + \frac {\sqrt {R^2-a^2}}{a}|))\\$

Comment: Thanks Doug, the revision works better but I don't get the same answer using my formula versus yours. For R = 1, h = 4 and a = 0.5, I get a volume of .4611 versus yours at .6981.

Comment: I don't see your formula.  What is your answer in terms of $\pi?$ hat do you get if you set $a = 0$?

Comment: When I set $a = 0$, I get $2.0944$ which is half the volume of the cone. Your formula gets exactly the same. My formula is immediately beneath my cone sketch. So when I set $a = 0.1$, I would expect the volume to diminish by $~ .4$ compared to the $a = 0$ volume. My formula diminishes by $.46$ which is too much and yours diminishes by $.19$ which is too little.

Comment: @PhilH I see my problem, I had the wrong lower bound.  Now we have a logarithm in the formula.  And I am not sure I have all of my signs correct at this point

Comment: Shouldn't your last but one line be:

Comment: I got cut off..........You subtracted a $1/3 HR^3 from 1/2HR^2$ to get $1/6HR^2$ which doesn't work for squares and cubes.

Comment: $\frac 12 Ha^2\cot a - \frac 16 \frac {H}{R} a^3 \csc \theta \cot \theta$ evaluated at $\arcsin \frac {a}{R}$ lower bound.  $\csc (\arcsin \frac {a}{R})  = \frac {R}{a}$ giving $-\frac 13 Ha\sqrt {R^2-a^2}$

Comment: Yes this gets the same answer as my equation. Very good, now I'll study it to learn something new. Thanks so much.